# Automatically rearranging the rows of an image

Tags: php, c++, python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Could someone tell me what the terminology is for automatically rearranging the rows of an image like this:

[image: Image1]

To make it look like this:

[image: Image 2]

If possible does anyone have any examples of how this can be done?

Comment: You are asking for an algorithm. An algorithm is a sequence of steps to solve a well-defined problem. You did not define the problem at all. What defines the permutation of rows you are looking for? Ability of OCR to make out some text in it? Smoothness of edges? Some fuzzy "looks 'good' to some humans" criteria? Closeness to another given picture? Something else entirely?

Comment: The problem is the random order, each row is rearranged at random so they are not in any particular order. If they were arranged in a set order or any order other than random, I may have been able to figure it out myself and not had to ask. Though I do suspect that "neighbor connectivity" may have some part to play when checking against the final image, I cannot be sure as that's something I'm not really familiar with.

Comment: There's no terminology for your problem because it's not very common, in fact I'd say it's unique.

Comment: It's called [Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence).

Answer (score 1):

You may get somewhere with a combination of integer programming, and measuring the number of connected components and image variance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to the reconstruction of shredded documents. Look for academic papers on "paper de-shredder" or "document reconstruction." Some university courses in image processing have notes and/or exercises online related to document reconstruction.

Instagram Engineering offered a reward to "unshred" and reconstitute an image. There's even some sample code to help get you started.
http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/

If you have some code already, please post it for review.